# Get top 10 items based on certain register using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

Using: MYSQL

So, i have this problem. I have a Table called tblUser, and this table has a level colum, so i need to get the level of one user, for example,

id: 1
    User: Pancho Villa
    Level: 15.

So i need to get the 9 register more who's level is below him and i don't have any idea how... so, this is an example, i get the ID of Pancho Villa:

```
id: 1
User: Pancho Villa  
Level: 15  

id: 25
User: Emiliano Zapata  
Level: 15

id: 14
User: Porfirio Díaz   
Level: 14

id: 7
User: Subcomandante Marcos<br>
Level: 13
```

& 6 more results

Comment: Are you simply trying to get the top 10 users sorted by Level?

Comment: No, i need to get 9 more users sorted by level based on an specific user, for example, if i get the id of Subcomandante Marcos, now i need 9 more users below him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this SQL

```
SELECT user,level
FROM tblUser
WHERE level <= (
    SELECT level
    From tblUser
    WHERE user = 'Pancho Villa'
)
AND user != 'Pancho Villa'
ORDER BY level DESC
LIMIT 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
select `User`,`Level` from tblUser where `Level` <= 15 Order by `Level` DESC
```